# Select em Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia. 
Tenho uma tabela com as colunas `Version`, `Updated`, `LastChanged`. 
Quero fazer uma consulta para selecionar o maior valor da versão, com o respetivo `LastChanged`, correspondente ao `Updated` = 1;

Fiz assim, mas não deu certo.

```
select Max(Version), LastChanged from BMTDatabaseUpdate where Updated=1
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o que necessita, inclusive postando amostra de dados e o resultado esperado? A frase " selecionar o maior valor da versão, com o respetivo LastChanged" pode gerar interpretações diferentes...

Comment: Para um mesmo valor de Version pode existir mais de uma linha, variando o valor de LastChanged?

Answer (score 1):

O enunciado deixa em aberto se, para o maior valor de Version, deve retornar todas as linhas (caso exista mais de uma) ou se deve obter o maior valor para o par (Version, LastChanged).

Considerando-se a segunda premissa, avalie o seguinte código:

```
-- código #1
with cteSeq as (
SELECT Version, LastChanged,
       Seq= row_number() over(order by Version desc, LastChanged desc)
  from BMTDatabaseUpdate
   where Updated = 1
)
SELECT Version, LastChanged
  from cteSeq
  where Seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem várias alternativas para obter o resultado desejado. Ficam aqui três alternativas.

A primeira usando uma "window function":

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
    SELECT Version, 
           LastChanged,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Version DESC, LastChanged DESC) RN
      FROM BMTDatabaseUpdate  
     WHERE Updated = 1  
) V
WHERE RN = 1
```

A segunda usando uma sub-query:

```
SELECT BMT.Version,
       MAX(BMT.LastChanged) LastChanged,
       BMT.Updated
  FROM BMTDatabaseUpdate BMT
 INNER JOIN 
 (
     SELECT MAX(Version) MVersion
       FROM BMTDatabaseUpdate
      WHERE Updated = 1
 ) MaiorVersao
   ON MaiorVersao.MVersion= BMT.Version
 WHERE BMT.Updated = 1 
 GROUP BY BMT.Version
```

Comment: O enunciado do que a Ana Carvalho solicita me parece incompleto, podendo gerar interpretações e sugestões diferentes. Postei comentário para ela, solicitando que esclareça melhor o que solicita e assim seja possível postarmos soluções específicas.